# Game Center Player Display Name Always "me" in the sandbox

Tags: ios, xcode, game-center

I am using the user's Game Center display name and player ID in order to maintain their profile on my server. When I went to test this, everything appears to execute properly, but the user's display name for my sandbox account shows up as "Me," rather than my display name attached to my account, "Billybobbo."

Is this supposed to happen in sandbox mode?

Console:

```
2013-08-31 18:51:37.054 [App Name][53230:907] Player ID: G:1682017882
2013-08-31 18:51:37.065 [App Name][53230:907] Player Display Name: Me
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anyone who may want to do something similar to what I am doing, Apple hasn't made these properties very clear. The property that I wanted to access in this case was not the user's `displayName`, but actually the user's `alias`.