# Is GKPlayer's displayName for GKLocalPlayer always "Me"?

Tags: ios6, ios7, game-center

When testing in sandbox-mode, `[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] displayName]` always returns `@"Me"`. Does this also happen on Game Center's production servers?

Partial solution would be to use the `alias` property, but Apple explicitly says:

> A player’s alias is used when a player is not a friend of the local
>   player. Typically, you never display the alias string directly in your
>   user interface. **Instead use the *displayName* property**.

And for `displayName` it says:

> The display name for a player depends on whether the player is a
>   friend of the local player authenticated on the device. **(A)** If the player
>   is a friend of the local player, then the display name is the actual
>   name of the player. **(B)** If the player is not a friend, then the display
>   name is the player’s alias.

Which is preferred for the `GKLocalPlayer`: `@"Me"` or `alias` or something completely different? How would/did you solve this?

---

Related question: [Game Center Player Display Name Always "me" in the sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554226/game-center-player-display-name-always-me-in-the-sandbox)

Answer (score 0):

At least it is a localized "me". For example, if the system language is German, `displayName` is "Ich" instead of "Me".

Regarding which name to display for the local player, I think it's more of a gameplay question, so each game can decide on its own.